# how to change body tag background image opacity

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found a few already existing questions similar to this but they are not exactly what I am looking for...

What I am trying to do is to change the `<body>` tag opacity from 0 to 1 using transition when the page gets loaded in `XXX.php` file. My code works fine, except the background image does not seem to be affected by transition.

Some sample code to give you rough idea how I am trying to achieve this.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <body style="background='url(..LINK..) rgb(0, 0, 0) 0% 0% no-repeat'">
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s; /*will skip webkit, etc here*/
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery('body').css('opacity', 1);
}
```

All the content behaves properly, and get opacity from 0 to 1 in 3 seconds as expected, however background-image gets loaded straight away. I want it to take 3 seconds to change opacity from 0 to 1 as well.

I have tried to apply CSS and JS to `<html>` tag, but it still makes the same effect.

Also, I neither can modify that `XXX.html` file nor have not got access to `background: 'url("...")'` value in that context so cannot manipulate effect with JS.

Any suggestions how to solve it?

**EDIT**
I want the initial `<body>` opacity to be 0. And when all the content loads, start changing opacity from 0 to 1 in i.e. 3 seconds

Comment: you want the page to fade in from `0` to `1` on load?

Comment: @PhpDude  yes, want it to be opacity : 0. and when all the content loads, the start changing opacity from 0 to 1 in 3 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using body:before a "mask" can be added which can then be faded out when the document is ready jQuery shorthand for doc ready is $(function() {...}) or adding javascript just before  has the same effect. The CSS can handle the transitioning via use of classes. The javascript then handles adding/removing the classes to invoke the CSS transition. The only part which has slight disconnect is when the transition is complete the mask needs to be removed or pushed back so that it no longer blocks the  this can be done with a timeout that matches the transition time. See the jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/6p3ovena/

```
(function($) {
  var body = $("body");
  $(function() {
    body.removeClass("before-load");
    setTimeout(function() {
      body.addClass("after-transition");
    }, 3000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do, where you override the inline `background-size` (set it to 0) and create a pseudo that inherits its background image

*If you want to keep the jQuery to kick of the animation I added a 2:nd sample last in my answer*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background-size: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
}
body,
body::before {
  animation: slides 2.5s linear 0.5s forwards;   /*  0.5s delay, 2.5s duration  */
}

@keyframes slides {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

body > div {
  position: relative;  /*  needed on all direct children  */
  background: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body style='background-image: url("http://placehold.it/400x200/f00/fff?text=sample image");'>

  <div>
    Your content
  </div>

</body>
```

Sample 2

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('body').addClass('showme');

});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background-size: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
}

body.showme,
body.showme::before {
  animation: showme 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showme {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

body > div {
  position: relative;  /*  needed on all direct children  */
  background: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style='background-image: url("http://placehold.it/400x200/f00/fff?text=sample image");'>

  <div>
    Your content
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with CSS :after.

Please, have a look at https://fiddle.jshell.net/ps5v8efc/.

Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the offered solution, but I cannot use it. I have not got access to background image URL and thats why I cannot create :after css rule

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
jQuery('body').css('opacity',0);
    setTimeout(function(){
          jQuery('body').css('opacity', 1);
    },3000)
```

Comment: This does not make the initial <body> background image to be invisible

Comment: i editet my answer  jQuery('body').css('opacity',0);  before time out

Comment: as per my original issue, opacity : 0 still does not make background-image to be transparent